# Objectbox: How to initialize ToMany<> relation in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, objectbox

```
@Entity
data class EmailMessage (
    @Id var id: Long = 0,
    var subject: String = "",
    var body: String = "",
    var attachments: ToMany<Attachment>? = null,
)
```

for 'attachments', Is there a better way to do it without assigning null?

Comment: Have you tried `lateinit`?

Comment: Not possible to use lateinit for primary constructor

Comment: I know, but you could put this particular property in the body

Comment: objextbox calls getAttachments() which would throw an exception " lateinit property attachments has not been initialized"

Comment: If it does before setting it, yes that’s a problem

Comment: Looks like the issue caused by Roboelectric. Shifted to AdndroidInstrumentaitonTest and it worked fine with lateinit.

Comment: Github URL: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/220